# API Gateway can't access Cookie header

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I seem unable to map the Cookie header in API gateway to the input for my lambda. I have set the following body mapping template:

```
{
    "rawCookieString" : "$input.params().header.get('Cookie')" 
}
```

and it fails to map the Cookie header leaving the field blank. If I change Cookie to be any other header eg "Test" it works fine! Any ideas why the Cookie header seems to be ignored?

Comment: Could you clarify. Is this from the test invoke functionality from the console or with your deployed API?

Comment: @BobKinney The test invoke from the API gateway dashboard works fine but when deployed it does not pick the header up

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your error, I am able to get Cookie headers to work correctly. Can you post how you are testing this? Alternatively, if you post on the [AWS Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=199&start=0) we can look up your API configuration and potentially offer additional debugging for why you might be encountering issues.

Answer (score 3):

I have met the same problem yesterday. I solve this issue by changing the cookie value that we want to send to lambda.

The reason probably is the format of you Cookie is not correct.

if you send cookie like this:

```
curl -v --cookie "CXLZOYXA" https://XXXXXX.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/beta/pets
```

the cookie wouldn't be added to the header of the request header(In AWS API Gateway,you can get the cookie).

```
> GET /beta/pets HTTP/1.1
> Host: p6useiue14.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
```

if you send cookie like this :

```
curl -v --cookie "name=CXLZOYXA" https://XXXXX.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/beta/pets
```

the cookie will be added to the header of the request header.

```
> GET /beta/pets HTTP/1.1
> Host: p6useiue14.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: name=CXLZOYXA
>
```